# How do prioritize matches in the beginning of strings in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch instance full of documents containing movie and series titles.

When I run this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "Name^2",
              "SeriesName^1.5",
              "Description"
            ],
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "prefix_length": 2,
            "query": "game"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

... I get titles like "The big game", "Hunger games", "War game", etc.

However, I would like to get titles starting with "game" BEFORE titles just containing "game".

When a user searches for "game", they expect titles like "Game of Thrones" and "Game change", before "The imitation game".

How can I make this more *precise*? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like below :

```
{ "query": {
    "prefix" : { "Name" : "game" }
  }
}
```

Please refer the documentation for the same [Elasticsearch Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/blog/starts-with-phrase-matching)

To do this your field/property **have to** be tokenized as a *keyword*, see query below. One can also add an additional lowercase filter in mapping for your field/property.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "analyzer_startswith": {
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                        "filter": "lowercase"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "test_index": {
            "properties": {
                "Name": {
                    "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "index_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but won't these alternatives exclude titles with "game" in the middle of the Name string? I want to _prioritize_ titles starting with "game", but also include the rest. And how can I use multi_match, fuzzy etc. at the same time?

Comment: Fire 2 different queries...first for the starts with..and second for the contains...merge the results

Comment: Wait ... when running your prefix query I get: "Assassination Games" ... I'm sorry but this was not what I wanted. I would like to get the documents matching the START of the string in the field Name.

Comment: how did index the property...what the mapping for it...have you applied the above mapping

Comment: The way you wrote your answer made me think the indexing was another option. I understand now that I actually *have to* index it with keyword.

Comment: it is obvious that the field/property needs be indexed with the above index analyser...