# sort elasticsearch result so that the result with keyword in the beginning appear first

Tags: elasticsearch

I am searching for the word "stud" , and i am expecting the result in this order

"occupation": "Student (Betriebswirtschaft)"

"occupation": "Student (Humanmedizin)"

"occupation": "Student (Bauwesen)"

"occupation": "Student (Chemie)"

"occupation": "Student (Architektur)"

"occupation": "Oberstudienrat/Oberstudienrätin"

"occupation": "Nagelstudioinhaber"

**But I get the result in this sequence**

"occupation": "Student (Betriebswirtschaft)"

"occupation": "Student (Humanmedizin)"

"occupation": "Oberstudienrat/Oberstudienrätin"

"occupation": "Student (Bauwesen)"

"occupation": "Student (Chemie)"

"occupation": "Nagelstudioinhaber"

"occupation": "Student (Architektur)"

like these words "Oberstudienrat/Oberstudienrätin" ,  "Nagelstudioinhaber" should be at the end , Because i first want to see the results which have "stud" in the begining and then the words which have "stud" in the middle

```
{  
  "query":{  
  "bool":{  
     "must":[  
        {  
           "query_string":{  
              "query":"*Stud*",
              "fields":[  
                 "occupation"
              ]
           }
        }
     ]
  }
},
"rescore":{  
  "window_size":500,
  "query":{  
     "score_mode":"multiply",
     "rescore_query":{  
        "bool":{  
           "should":[  

              {  
                 "match":{  
                    "occupation":{  
                       "query":"Stud*",
                       "boost":3
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     },
     "query_weight":2.7,
     "rescore_query_weight":3.2
  }
```

}
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56664377/how-do-prioritize-matches-in-the-beginning-of-strings-in-elasticsearch/56665097#56665097

Answer (score 0):

Here if your field is tokenized, it is difficult for your to achieve the sorting on the same field.

Modify the field for achieving sorting. This field should of raw type or apply only keyword tokenizer and lowercase tokenizer to it. The raw field will not be analyzed, meaning it will be one term in total, thus it can be used for sort. In order to do this you'll have to update your mapping and then use the reindex api in order to update your data.

Your field will have mapping like

```
PUT my_index
    {
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "city": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "raw": { 
                "type":  "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And use the new field for sorting.

```
GET my_index/_search

    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "city": "york" 
        }
      },
      "sort": {
        "city.raw": "asc" 
      }
    }
```